# unexpeccted token const in database.ts

Tags: node.js, json, nestjs

i am new to nest.js i have created a project and i connect it to a databse i have created database.ts file here it is

```json
export default {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    type: 'mysql',
    port: process.env.DB_PORT || 3306,
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    entities: ['src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    synchronize: process.env.DB_SYNCRONIZE === 'true',
    logging: process.env.DB_LOGGING === 'true',
  };
```

when I strat nest js on local host 3001 i am getting following error C:\Users\kukab\Desktop\name\api\dist\config\database.d.ts:1
declare const _default: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
[image]
here is my package.json

```json
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/node": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^0.5.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^4.6.1",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^6.1.1",
    "@nestjsx/crud": "^4.6.2",
    "class-transformer": "^0.3.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.12.2",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "nestjs-config": "^1.4.7",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.28"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.3",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^13.9.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "3.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "3.9.1",
    "eslint": "7.7.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "jest": "26.4.2",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "26.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "ts-node": "9.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

Comment: It might be version conflicts, are you using the latest Node/npm versions?

Comment: ye si am using latest but i am following blog and I think blog was made on old version

Answer (score 1):

the issue is with how ES6 modules are emulated in CommonJS

change your `export default` to

```
module.exports = {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    type: 'mysql',
    port: process.env.DB_PORT || 3306,
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    entities: ['src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    synchronize: process.env.DB_SYNCRONIZE === 'true',
    logging: process.env.DB_LOGGING === 'true',
  };
```